# How to set the site permissions to new users in a Django form

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have this class in my Django/Mezzanine project:

```
class SitePermission(models.Model):
    """
    Permission relationship between a user and a site that's
    used instead of ``User.is_staff``, for admin and inline-editing
    access.
    """

    user = models.OneToOneField(user_model_name, verbose_name=_("Author"),
        related_name="%(class)ss")
    sites = models.ManyToManyField("sites.Site", blank=True,
                                   verbose_name=_("Sites"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Site permission")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Site permissions")
```

When in admin and selecting one of the sites and press the save button. A record gets to the database with the permissions.

**How would I do the the following on the front end:**

1. Create a new site + user (in the same form)
2. Create new site (subdomain) as the username. Like it's the same input form.
3. Add the site permissions to the newly created user
4. Add Site Title
5. Add more username data after this

**This is my current view that's handling this:**

```
def create_site(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateSite(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/welcome/')
            except IntegrityError:
                form._errors["domain"] = ["Domain must be unique!"]
    else:
        form = CreateSite()
    return render(request, "includes/create_site.html", {'form': form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
class CreateSite(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ['domain' , 'name']
```